Tag wiki (figurative) review queue depth (and maybe a favor)
In two days it will be three weeks since I posted about the firefox-addon-sdk tag and suggested edits to the wiki. There was some discussion (now deleted, presumably by moderators) in the comments about whether I should suggest an edit and await review rather than attempt to persuade someone with more rep to make an edit.
In any case, I suggested an edit.
My understanding from reading some older posts about review queues is that there is no separate queue for the tag wiki. Nevertheless, the kind of content and edit are different from regular q&a. Is it usual for a suggested edit to the tag wiki to take three or so weeks? My few other suggested (non-tag wiki) edits took less than a week. I can also imagine that few people may want to approve an edit on a topic of which they have little comfort, while simultaneously don't want to reject it for much the same reason. My understanding is also that people can't look at the whole queue. They're handed tasks one-by-one, so my edit may not get handed to anyone for a while, based on some unknown scheduling algorithm.
Considering that an edit was overdue by six or eight years, I don't think the suggestion will get stale particularly quickly. Also in the last eight years, there might be a few other suggested edits waiting for approval, if the queue goes that deep.
So what should my expectations be? Is three weeks a long time or not so much? Alternatively is there a way to see if any particular edit is acceptable or somehow requires more thought and work? I'm about 5k rep away from 5k rep, so it may be a while before I can see for myself.

"Is it usual for a suggested" yes; there is a very small percentage of users that can approve them (5k+ rep), and a small number for those visit the review queue in question. According to this SEDE only 0.2% of users can approve it, and that.ingores users who are active, or have reviewed (recently).

@ThomA, /help/privileges makes it seem like everyone at 2k can review all edits, although at 1.5.k everyone can make new tags (which seems an odd disparity). Is there somewhere that has more detail on the extra requirements beyond rep? (I kind of have 2 objectives here: get my edit approved, but also understand the mechanism better.)

@Nanigashi Tag wikis are not posts; you need to read further up where it says "approve tag wiki edits" for users with 5,000 reputation.

To be honest, my expectation time is much longer than three weeks, especially for niche tags.

It's also worth noting, @Nanigashi, that unlike post edits, where you gain the privilege to both unilaterally edit them and approve suggestions by others 2k rep, the privilege at 5k is only to peer review suggested edits to wikis,  not unilaterally edit them; that privilege is at 20k reputation.


My understanding from reading some older posts about review queues is that there is no separate queue for the tag wiki. Nevertheless, the kind of content and edit are different from regular q&a.

Correct, these end up in the suggested edits review along with suggested edits on normal posts. However, tag wikis are trickier to review and therefore require 5000+ rep, as opposed to 2000+ rep for normal review edits.

Is it usual for a suggested edit to the tag wiki to take three or so weeks?

That's quite a long time. Although nowadays the queue tends to be near full at all time, which means 500 posts waiting review. Lots of high rep users are boycotting moderation work for various reasons having to do with how the company handles the network. There was a big trust crisis some 5 years ago after which the network lost a whole lot of diamond moderators/high rep user moderators. In addition there was a moderator strike last summer for similar reasons. The review queues still seem to be suffering from the fallout from these two events.

I can also imagine that few people may want to approve an edit on a topic of which they have little comfort, while simultaneously don't want to reject it for much the same reason.

Correct. Normally tag wikis are tricky for that reason alone. But also because you have to check for plagiarized content, which is time consuming but very much needed.

My understanding is also that people can't look at the whole queue.

No but if one knows what to look for, it is possible to filter after certain tags. There is a bit of reviewer vs tag matching at some extent. Or one can go through a user profile and see what that particular user has suggested (I did so here to peek at your particular suggestions).

Alternatively is there a way to see if any particular edit is acceptable or somehow requires more thought and work?

When reviewed, the reviewer will leave a message for you if it was rejected telling you the reason(s) why. But it requires a human reviewer still.

Anyway in this particular case your edits seemed sensible and I don't think domain knowledge is required to approve of them, so I went ahead and approved them just now. What would make edits even better though, would be if you can include a section about tag usage guidance. In this case perhaps just something like for example "always use this tag in combination with the firefox tag" (if that makes sense). Also consider if the tag could be ambiguous and if there's some potential misuse because of it that need to be clarified.
Good tag wikis don't focus so much on what a certain technology is but on how to use the tag itself. There could sometimes be tag-specific policies specified by the community such as "if only tag x is used without a certain version of x specified, the latest version is assumed".

Thanks, dude. As for guidance, I doubt it would be of interest to general consumers of the [tag:firefox] tag. Perhaps the last sentence of the guidance should be "After 2017, this tag should be used only for questions about the use of the SDK with legacy Firefox forks, such as Pale Moon and Basilisk." instead of "Although it is obsolete for versions of Firefox released since 2017, it can still be useful for some legacy Firefox forks." Thoughts?

@Nanigashi It's rather: which more widely-used tag do you suspect that those interested in the specific tag are following? Attracting the right kind of people to questions using the specialized tag. As for the contents of this specific wiki I really have nothing to say, this is very far from the stuff I normally work with.

A [tag:palemoon] tag exists. A Basilisk tag doesn't. I'll think about it.
